# Режим киоска на Android

Tags: android

Делаю терминал оплаты (в первом приближении), интерфейс реализуется в виде планшета на Android, убранного в сейфовый ящик, снаружи доступен только экран. 
Одно из требований заказчика, ставящее меня в тупик - портируемость на другие модели планшетов, т.е. редактировать программу или прошивку никто не будет, а какой версии андроид установлен заранее не известно (от 4.1 и выше).

Нужно запретить пользователю выходить из приложения и залезать в настройки. Все "шторки" и софтовые кнопки (если они есть) надо скрыть.

Есть ли какой-нибудь метод реализовать это без привязки к версии андроида?

Если возможно, надо обойтись без root'ования.

Comment: в чём именно заключается вопрос? акцентируйте этот момент, пожалуйста, в тексте самого вопроса.

Comment: Без root прав не обойтись, они нужны для того, что бы скрыть верхнюю шторку. Так же проблема будет с кнопкой ```home```, т.к. ее нельзя переопределить как кнопку ```back```, единственное что можно сделать это зарегистрировать приложение как ```launcher``` и заранее установить его по умолчанию. К тому же если кнопки "железные" то их не скроешь в режиме ```full screen```, если только закрыть физически.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё зависит от конкретной версии Android.

Если 5.0 и выше, то там уже есть штатные функции для работы с режимом киоска.
Для более ранних версий это сделать сложнее, но всё же реально:

- Автоматический перезапуск через манифест;
- Перехват нажатия системных кнопок;
- Блокировка панели статуса.

Это вкратце. Более подробно можно посмотреть в [этой статье](http://www.azoft.ru/blog/android-kiosk-mode/).