# Вопрос: доработка прошивки Android

Tags: android, linux, прошивка

Возможно ли на Android устройстве а именно планшете переделать немного прошивку (без разницы какой производитель и модель), что нужно: переделать прелоадер при загрузке устройства, а после запуска ОС открыть только одно приложение и заблокировать возможность из этого приложения выйти. Или может проще будет установить Linux на устройство и из под него производить эти манипуляции?

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: на всякий случай, для просветления ваших запудренных кем-то мозгов: программа linux там **уже** есть. именно она и загружается и обеспечивает работу операционной системы android (ну, если, «это» можно, конечно, назвать операционной системой).

Answer (score 0):

Это приложение называется Launcher. Вам нужно найти или написать этот ланчер так чтоб он открывал только ваше приложение. Тема широкая, но легче всего поискать по словам android kiosk.

[Режим киоска на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480536/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android)